# Is there any open source video camera security and surveillance solution which support any IP camera?

Tags: surveillance

Is there any open source video camera security and surveillance solution which support any IP camera?

[Zoneminder](http://www.zoneminder.com/) is one of them, but I am not sure if it supports any brand of IP camera or has any brand limitation.

Comment: I doubt you will find one that meets the goal of supporting *any* camera.  Different cameras even from the same manufacturer use different methods to deliver the video stream.  You should probably focus on software the supports a few different cameras that you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

[Motion](http://www.lavrsen.dk/twiki/bin/view/Motion/WebHome) would probably be your best candidate. I've used it in the past with many different brands of IP cameras and have never had a problem. It'll also use local USB-connected cameras or V4L devices as well. Motion also does motion detection, periodic snapshots, etc.

Comment: dont know about Zoneminder but i've used Motion and seems nice. It did its job with an USB camera.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [list of supported hardware](http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_hardware) in ZoneMinder.

And here's [how to check your camera](http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/Documentation#Check_that_your_Camera_Works.21) for possible issues.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've spent a good amount of time with ZoneMinder.  Its a bit of work to setup but will worth it.  Once you have everything setup the interface is very friendly and straight forward.  You can setup hot zones for detection, scheduling, ect.

I havn't tried motion, but it definitely looks like a good candidate.